# Linq to XML - SmarterMail API response to jQuery dataTables

Tags: c#, jquery, json, linq, linq-to-xml

Ok, looked everywhere and tried what feels like every possible solution.  So, it must be something simple.

I'm using the SmarterMail API to return a list of Mailing Lists.  I want to display the results in a jQuery DataTable which expects a list of string arrays.  How can I take my resulting list of strings and convert it to a list of string arrays?  The following code almost works but I end up with only the first letter of each Mailing List name.

Using .NET C# MVC.  Here is the method from my Controller.

```
public ActionResult getMailingLists(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    svcMailListAdmin.PreInvoke();
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("AuthUserName", SM_AuthUserName);
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("AuthPassword", SM_AuthPassword);
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("DomainName", SM_DomainName);

    svcMailListAdmin.Invoke("GetMailingListsByDomain");
    svcMailListAdmin.PostInvoke();

    var resultXML = svcMailListAdmin.ResultXML;

    var resultList = resultXML.Root.Elements("listNames")
                        .Elements("string")
                        .OrderBy(i => (string)i)
                        .Select(i => (string)i)
                        .ToList();

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = resultList.Count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = resultList.Count,
        aaData = resultList
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a slight change and now it seems to work.  I can also use this as a model for cases where I need to return multiple columns.

```
public ActionResult getMailingLists(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    svcMailListAdmin.PreInvoke();
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("AuthUserName", SM_AuthUserName);
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("AuthPassword", SM_AuthPassword);
    svcMailListAdmin.AddParameter("DomainName", SM_DomainName);

    svcMailListAdmin.Invoke("GetMailingListsByDomain");
    svcMailListAdmin.PostInvoke();

    var resultXML = svcMailListAdmin.ResultXML;

    var resultsList = resultXML.Root.Elements("listNames")
                    .Elements("string")
                    .Select(i => new List<string>()
                    {
                        (string)i
                    }).ToList();

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = resultsList.Count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = resultsList.Count,
        aaData = resultsList
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```